# Valet and Laravel 5.5 Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-valet

I just started a new project and I use Valet for all my new projects. I also use a mysql DB that is installed on my local machine. It works on all my old projects using Laravel 5.4, 5.3 and 5.2. For some reason, I get this error.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = john.doe@example.com limit 1)
```

My .env file looks like this.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=new_project
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

And as I said before, this works on all my old projects.

If I run tinker and for example run a simple call to the database, the connection works. So this error is only in the browser.

```
$users = App\User::all();
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#752
     all: [],
   }
```

Any clues?

Comment: You need to add password of your mysql database for the connection

Comment: Have you set the relevant permissions for root user to the table?

Comment: This is all set up by the Laravel Framework. It works just fine if I run older versions of Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear cache:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Laravel can remember old database credentials